# Access json object in each object

Tags: javascript, json

[image: JSON OBJECT]

Hi , how do I access the json object ? I only can access for each clouds , coord , main . I can't access any item in the clouds , main ,and cooord .

here is my jquery that fetch the api .

```
$(function(){

 var $currentWeather = $('#data');

 $.ajax({

 type:'GET',

 url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=9771952d2d67da2146a235657f2e4cf9',

success:function(data)
  {
   console.log('success',data);
   console.log(data.coord[0])
  }
  });
});
```

And here my json raw

[json raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVgHv.png)

Comment: please paste your JSON output in here. Oh, one more thing.. Show us what you've done.

Comment: Please prefer text over images wherever possible. Texts are easy to copy, paste and test in some other place.

Comment: You can access them but then you say you can't? What is the problem you are facing, post your [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you can access clouds, coord and main then all you need is to use the . notation and access the fields in each of the objects. (e.g. clouds.all, coord.lon and coord.lat, main.temp and main.pressure)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to display it in your html something along the lines of this
{{succes.main['message']}}
you acces your parent object with succes then withing succes you select main, as a attribute of main you can acces message or your other values.
edit if you just want to log it:
console.log(data.main['message']); 
Or 
console.log(data.succes.main['message']);